# Using polymer-gestures to test custom element

Tags: unit-testing, polymer

Why is [this test](https://github.com/leoj3n/swiper-slider/blob/master/test/basic-test.html#L54-L61) causing the following failure and error?

```
expected 'NO. ONE' to equal 'ITEM TWO'
               <unknown> at /swiper-slider/test/basic-test.html:59
      Object.Fake.downAt at /polymer-gestures/test/js/fake.js:98
  Object.Fake.downOnNode at /polymer-gestures/test/js/fake.js:89
     Context.<anonymous> at /swiper-slider/test/basic-test.html:56
```

`polymer-gestures/test/js/fake.js` is failing to find the target in [this method](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-gestures/blob/master/test/js/fake.js#L41-L43), called from [this method](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-gestures/blob/master/test/js/fake.js#L91-L99) but I can't narrow down the exact culprit.

My hunch is that it has something to do with the `div.swiper-button-next` element being [appended as a child on the fly](https://github.com/leoj3n/swiper-slider/blob/master/swiper-slider.html#L158) and use of `document.querySelector('swiper-slider /deep/ div.swiper-button-next')` in [the test](https://github.com/leoj3n/swiper-slider/blob/master/test/basic-test.html#L55).

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that one of a few things is happening.

1. the div.swiper-button-next isn't in the DOM by the time you make the call. Either work a callback into your system to fire when everything is done (then check the value inside that callback), or (just to test if this is actually the problem) put a manual setTimeout to delay the query selector and assertion for a bit.
2. Polymer's `targetAt` function uses elementFromPoint() internally. Double check to make sure you don't have any overlays (core-overlay tends to crap all over my window sometimes...) and that the element you really want to tap is actually the element being found. Don't be afraid to put some debugging/console.log statements into the actual polymer source code to see what it is finding there.
3. I haven't spent too much time looking over the test, but your slideEls[1] could possibly have changed since you queried for it. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a "non-live" nodelist, so changes to the DOM don't update your selection.